# What is model class of SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////tmp/test.db'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)                             


class User(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)

    def __init__(self, username, email):
        self.username = username
        self.email = email

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.username
```

This code I have found in SQLAlchemy documentation. `db=SQLAlchemy(app)` It means that db is a object. class `User(db.Model)` by looking at the line it looks like that db is a module name.

what basically db is?can someone explain me.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass
I have read this but not able to understand.

Comment: Please do the beginner python tutorial on python.org . You lack the basics. :)

Answer (score 0):

The db = SQLAlchemy(app) is the way to set the db variable with the correct app context, is basically to register the application on db instance, we use this to associate the application bound to the current context